# Is it possible to have text positioned next to a fixed image jumbotron on the same row?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jumbotron that has an image with the following details:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('Images/Example.png'); background-attachment: fixed; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Using this, I can have text positioned next to it like this:

[image]

But is it possible to position text next to it like this:

[image]

Can I have text next to a jumbotron, not within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach for this question

```html
<div style=height:500px>
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:url('https://assets3.classic-assets.com/product_photo/22868/large_Poly_HotPink_pms226up_1471502442.jpg');background-attachment:fixed; height:50%; width:50%; float:left"></div>

  <div style="background-color:green; height:50%; width:50%; float:left">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lily.
You can achieve this by using a container and denoting a row/column hierarchy like the following.
By using 'ROW', it tells bootstrap to look for any columns underneath and keep them on the same line.

This is scalable up until the 12th column element, I think.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Just including this so I have bootstrap to show you the output. -->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    This is a jumbly Trop
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    HEY! OI! TEXT! HERE!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```